# DB2 Selecting a specific XML content with XMLQUERY

Tags: sql, xml, db2

This is a sample XML. In this XML i want to select the name "Marc Intes" but i am having problems with it.

```
<Person Name="Marc Intes">
```

Here is how i did my query, this XML document is under the column named GUEST.

```
XMLQUERY('$GUEST/Person@Name')
```

But it is giving me an error saying:

```
SQL16002N  An XQuery expression has an unexpected token "@" following 
"ST/Person". Expected tokens may include: "". Error QName=err:XPST0003.  
SQLSTATE=10505
```

Where did i go wrong? I am really confused right now.

Comment: http://amolnpujari.wordpress.com/2008/04/12/db2-native-xml/ might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems with your query. Firstly, XML attributes are also an XPath dimension, so the attribute reference should be separated by a slash:

```
XMLQUERY('$GUEST/Person/@Name')
```

Secondly, XMLQUERY is supposed to return an XML sequence, and a standalone attribute cannot be made into a sequence, so you need to cast it to an SQL type instead:

```
XMLCAST ( XMLQUERY('$GUEST/Person/@Name') AS VARCHAR(20) )
```

Comment: Thanks alot man! I am still learning about queries. this works 100%